# Showing errors in Eclipse but program is runing

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, pygame, linux-mint

```
1     '''
2     Created on Nov 19, 2013
3   
4     @author: martins
5     '''
6     bif = "background.jpg"
7     mif = "ball.png"
8   
9     import pygame, sys
10    from pygame.locals import *
11    
12    pygame.init()
13    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800),0,32) #izveido logu
14    
15    background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()#pārveido bildes
16    mouse_c = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()#pārveido bildes
17   
18    while True:
19        for event in pygame.event.get():
20            if event.type == QUIT:#nodrošina, ka programma pilnīgi aizveras
21              pygame.quit()
22                sys.exit()
23      
24      screen.blit(background,(0,0)) #nokopē backgroundu uz ekrāna(logā)
25      
26      x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()# noskaidro peles koardinātas
27      x-=mouse_c.get_width()/2 #ieliek kursoru bildei vid
28      y-=mouse_c.get_height()/2
29        
30      screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))#nokpē 
31       
32      pygame.display.update()
```

I do not know why this is showing, but it is quite annoying because the code is running fine and doing what is supposed to do, i believe there are some trouble with interpreter, but i cannot figure out what it is. Thanks for help!

on line 10: Unused in wild import: Color, Rect, color
on line 12: Undefined variable from import: init
on line 20: Undefined variable: QUIT
on line 21: Undefined variable from import: quit
P.s. don't mind the coments they are for myself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are warnings, not errors. For example, the first is telling you that although you have used a `wild import` (e.g. `import *`) from `pygame.locals`, you aren't using some of the methods and attributes that would provide. According to the Python style guide ([PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)) you shouldn't use wildcard imports, or import multiple libraries on one line (i.e. `import pygame, sys`).

Comment: Well i figured it out. Changed some settings on Eclipse and now everything seems to work fine.